# A mark that I believe I will receive?

Tags: single-word-requests

I'm trying to find a word for a 'self assessment' type card.

It has to mean something along the lines of "mark I thought I would receive" or "mark I am confident that I will receive".

It will be used something like this: "[word] Mark" or "Mark [word]" above a column showing a fraction or percentage mark. This will be alongside "Mark Received".

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I recommend "mark [expected](http://www.ldoceonline.com/dictionary/expect)" to pair nicely with "mark received".

> to think that something will happen because it seems likely or has been planned

Comment: ...And that is perfect, thank you. I will probably accept this tomorrow.

Comment: @Amziraro Glad to help. No rush. Others may have another idea that works.

Comment: This is exactly what I use

Answer (score 1):

As I understand students would fill this in, based on their assessment of their performance (and not e.g. their wishes). I would suggest:

mark-**[estimate](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/spellcheck/english/?q=self-estimate)**:

> noun
>
> An approximate calculation or judgement of the value, number, quantity, or extent of something (ODO)

or one could call it an estimated mark or a self-estimated mark. The students could estimate their mark based on the number of questions they are confident they have answered correctly, e.g.

Another (similar) choice would be:

[predicted](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/predict)

> Say or estimate that (a specified thing) will happen in the future or will be a consequence of something
>
> *it is too early to predict a result*

although this doesn't imply so strongly that you are basing your prediction on something specific like *estimate* does.

A third option, similar to Catia's expected can be:

[anticipated](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/anticipate)

> regard as probable; expect or predict: